# Wireguard VPN works on my iPhone, but not on my Windows 11 PC

Tags: linux, vpn, raspberry-pi, raspbian, wireguard

So I've been trying to turn my raspberry to a VPN server using PiVPN, WireGuard and DuckDNS. I've had some success as after configuring Wireguard on my iPhone the connection works. However, the same configuration does not work on my Windows PC and I haven't a clue why... Here's how the tunnel config files looks:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = uPcHJQ5JP60tn5gZiuJHEOsMrbsxyBIeZ/FZG4cziVk=
Address = 10.370.129.3/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = XHQHgjmRb5huQL0Xy+KwnqTgpspREZXNhDGqk9I8uWQ=
PresharedKey = Jfcmr9nYPC7T+AUCSLZjHgoSpa4TG4mFt+OthmHhnEE=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = XXX.duckdns.org:51820
```

Comment: What's not working - are you getting an error message or logs?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale The connection is showing status "active" without any errors, but there's actually no internet on my pc when connected to the vpn. No error messages whatsoever..